# Visual Studio workflow and StatusColumnCreated property

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

Apparently you do not get a custom status column if you are using farm solutions in contrast to any SPD workflow or VS app based workflows.

However you can set "StatusColumnCreated" property to "1" in your Elements.xml and voilà the column is being created automatically upon deployment of the workflow.

That's the good thing. The bad thing is: the column isn't ever used by my workflow.

In SPD we have stages which the status column reflects any time. What about Visual Studio workflows? Do I have to write to the automatically generated status column myself? In that particular case I'd prefer to create a custom column on my own suiting my needs.

Or am I doing something wrong? How does my workflow automatically set its custom status column to something a little bit more meaningful? I tried State Machine workflows too - no status column update whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across a solution [here](http://www.schaeflein.net/setting-workflow-status-in-visual-studio-and-sharepoint-designer/)

I'm not sure if that's really the best way to update the status column - it might not be a supported solution. It does work though.